# Flash AS3 Play FLV custom Button using class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi all I video playing using the FLVPlayback component. I know I can use one of multiple skins provided by adobe but I need to make my own simple play and pause buttons. I also need to do this within a class.

What I have is the FLVPlayback component called vid which fetches the video from an XML file and works fine. I also have a button called btn_play and the following code in the class file:

```
...
btn_play.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playvid);
...
    public function playvid (e:Event) {

    }
...
```

Im not sure what code to use to make the video actually play. Also will need one for pause too. Finally if you have any idea how I can assign keyboard entry to these buttons or just the video i.e. pressing p on the keyboard makes it play etc id be grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can control the FLVPlayback component though your class using this info here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html. Your play button code would look something like this:

```
public function playvid(e:Event):void
{
    //assume player is your FLVPlayback instance
    player.play();
}
```

To listen for keyboard events first attach a listener to the stage:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyPress);
```

Then when you catch the KeyBoardEvent you can perform actions based on the key code.

```
public function handleKeyPress(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    //convert the key's code to its value
    var pressed:String = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    //perform actions based on the value of pressed
    switch (pressed.toLowerCase()) {
        case "p":
            playvid(null);
        break;
        case "s":
            stopvid(null);
        break;
    }
}
```